# Generic type T is not recognized by gson in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm implementing a WebSocket JsonRPC client in kotlin like this:

```
     fun <T>call(methodName: String, params: List<Any>) : Future<T>{
        fun task(): () -> T = {
            var response: T? = null
            val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
            val request = RpcRequest(methodName, params).apply {
                callbacks[id.toString()] = {
//                    val type = object: TypeToken<RpcResponse<List<LightingGroup>>>() {}.type
                    val type = object: TypeToken<RpcResponse<T>>() {}.type
                    val rpcResponse : RpcResponse<T> = gson.fromJson(it, type)
                    response = rpcResponse.result
                    latch.countDown()
                }
            }
            val json = gson.toJson(request)
            println(json)
            send(json)
            if (!latch.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw TimeoutException("Timeout!")
            }

            response!!
        }

        return executor.submit(task())
    }
```

The clients sends an RpcRequest and expects a RpcResponse back in JSON format.

The data in the RpcResponse could be anything, and is, in this specific case a list of LightingGroups.

```
data class RpcResponse<T>(
    val id: Long,
    @SerializedName(value = "jsonrpc")
    val version: String = "2.0",
    val result: T,
    val error: Any?
)
```

```
data class LightingGroup(
    @SerializedName(value = "ID")
    val id: Long,
    @SerializedName(value = "Name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName(value = "Devices")
    val devices: List<LightingDevice>,
    @SerializedName(value = "Moods")
    val moods: List<LightingMood>,
    @SerializedName(value = "IsOn")
    val isOn: Boolean
)
```

The code that calls the "call" method looks like this:

```
val response = MainActivity.ws.call<List<LightingGroup>>("GetTradfriGroups", arrayListOf()).get()
println(response[0].name)
```

The problem comes with the conversion from the json to the generic type T.

When using the code:

```
val type = object: TypeToken<RpcResponse<List<LightingGroup>>>() {}.type
```

It works fine, but when using the following code it gets converted to a LinkedTreeMap.

```
val type = object: TypeToken<RpcResponse<T>>() {}.type
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit:

Minimal response json:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "Name": "Kitchen",
      "ID": 131074,
      "Devices": [
        {
          "Name": "Tradfri Bulb",
          "ID": 65572,
          "Type": 2,
          "State": 1,
          "LastSeen": "2020-05-17T04:37:13Z",
          "IsOn": false,
          "DimmerLevel": 25
        }
      ],
      "Moods": [
        {
          "Name": "FOCUS",
          "ID": 196614,
          "CreatedAt": "2018-12-11T17:01:17Z",
          "MoodProporties": [
            {
              "5707": 0,
              "5708": 0,
              "5709": 0,
              "5710": 0,
              "5711": 0,
              "5712": 0,
              "5850": 1,
              "5851": 254,
              "9003": 65572
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "IsOn": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you might need to have `T` as `reified` in `fun call`. If you include a (minimal) json string I can try to verify.

Comment: I've edited my post. Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working:

```
inline fun <reified T>call(methodName: String, params: List<Any>) : T {
        val type = object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type
        return executor.submit(task<T>(methodName, params, type)).get()
    }

    inline fun <reified T> task(methodName: String, params: List<Any>, type: Type): () -> T = {
        var response: T? = null
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        val request = RpcRequest(methodName, params).apply {
            callbacks[id.toString()] = {
                val rpcResponse = Gson().fromJson<T>(it, type)
                response = rpcResponse
                latch.countDown()
            }
        }
        val json = gson.toJson(request)
        println(json)
        send(json)
        if (!latch.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw TimeoutException("Timeout!")
        }

        response!!
    }
```